# How to terminate javascript function if condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello how can i terminate function daterange when param vale is not equal to "date"

because if condition is met and function daterange is executed the function still running even if param value is not equal to "date"
Note my code is inside asp update panel

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                                    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
                                        var concept = $(this).text();
                                        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
                                        $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
                                        if (param == "date") {
                                            $(function daterange () {
                                                $("#<%= txtsearch.ClientID %>").daterangepicker({
                                                    locale: {
                                                        format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else { //terminate the function }

                                    });
                                });

                                //Re-Create for on page postbacks
                                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                                prm.add_endRequest(function daterange() {
                                    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
                                        var concept = $(this).text();
                                        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
                                        $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
                                        if (param == "date") {
                                            $(function () {
                                                $("#<%= txtsearch.ClientID %>").daterangepicker({
                                                    locale: {
                                                        format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else { //terminate the function }
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If im getting this right - you are trying to exit the outer function - $(document).ready(function (e) {...  from within the event handler?

The only solution I can think of is by throwing exception in the event which is not handled outside in the function.

You can check this thread if you want: [Any way to exit outer function from within inner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747411/any-way-to-exit-outer-function-from-within-inner-function)

If you are just trying to terminate the event handler, then no need to do anythins, since the else block is at the end of the handler and it will terminate after it anyway. Hope this helps :)